# How to Increase the length of tooltip in datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in a winform and have set the property of ShowCellTips to true. The content of one of the cells has about 800characters. and the tooltip just shows 256 followed by ellipsis(...). is it possible to modify the property in some way so that tooltip displays the entire cell data .

Comment: what you are showing in the tooltip..?whole cell data..?

Comment: Yes. the tooltip displays whole cell data. Its the default tooltip that comes in with datagridview. I have just set the property ShowCellTips to true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showcelltooltips(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this. I test it with new `datagridview` nothing modified on it just wrote this code.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].ToolTipText =
                              dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

This is for first row second column example.